# Can't Create or Save File to Network Share in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm not certain when this problem started occuring, but it was approximately a few weeks ago when I upgraded from Visual Studio 2008 to 2010. I am on Windows XP Professional. The share is on a server running Windows Server 2003. I have a solution which contains a web site (accessed via UNC path, network share) and some class projects that reside on my local workstation. When I open a file from the website, and try to alter and save the file, I get the following error:

" Cannot access this file. Check security privileges over the network drive."

I've checked privileges on the root folder and I do indeed have full control. Could anyone give me any insight as to what I could be missing?

Comment: Just a guess, but do you have **both** sharing permissions and file system permissions?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the difference, could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out a sysadmin removed all permissions and user profiles from a chunk of servers and forgot to inform me. Thanks for the insight, all.

Answer (score 1):

**Are you running Windows Vista or Windows 7 with User Account Control (UAC) enabled?** If so, Visual Studio 2010 requires administrator permissions to do certain tasks, including IIS management and network share saving.

Try **opening Visual Studio 2010 with the `Run as Administrator` command**. Hope that solves your problem.

Comment: Actually, my workstation is Windows XP Professional and the server that the share is located is Server 2003 R2. I edited my question to clarify, thanks.

Comment: @lush Sorry, but I don't know why that's happening on XP. Good luck! :)